# How to use Round() or similar for UnitSpeed values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, numbers

I am using UnitSpeed to display the user's pace like this:

```
let formattedPace = FormatDisplay.pace(distance: distance, seconds: Int(stopwatch.elapsedTime), outputUnit: UnitSpeed.minutesPerMile)
```

this returns an example value like this "5.555 min/mi"
Question: How can I format the output to only show "5.5 min/mi"? I researched Apple's doc re: UnitSpeed but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain why this got downvoted? Was this a stupid question? I am honestly interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NumberFormatter` to achieve this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.roundingMode = .down

let number = 5.555
if let numberFormatted = formatter.string(for: number) {
    print(numberFormatted) // 5.5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To represent a measurement as a string, use a measurement formatter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter

It has a number formatter that will allow you to specify the rounding: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter